# Changing dataframe columns names by columns from another dataframe python

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe

I have a dataframe valence_data with columns `word1, word, word3, word4....`

And I have my second dataframe word_data with columns `1, 2, ,3 ,4 ...`

How can I replace the columns names in word_data by names from valence_data.

e.g. word_data with columns `word1, word, word3, word4....`

I am using pandas processing my data.

Thanks

Comment: if all the columns correspond directly to columns in the other dataframe, you can do `word_data.columns = valence_data.columns`, else you need `df.rename`

Comment: @Zulfiqaar thanks but I just noticed the names I want to take are the row names from valence_data instead of columns. How can I make that happen? They should correspond directly to all columns

Comment: to get row names you either extract `list(df.index)`, or if it is a column you need to get `list(df['your_column_name'])`

Comment: @Zulfiqaar Yes I am taking values from a column in valence_data. But now the problem is that after the columns are changed, the names start from the index column(first column). How can i skip the index column and start from the second one? thanks.

Comment: `valence_date[valence_data.columns[1]]`

Answer (score 1):

You need to use [DataFrame.rename](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rename.html)

```
original_names = ["1", "2", ...]
new_names = ["word1", "word2", ...]
new_columns = dict(zip(original_names, new_names))
df.rename(index=str, columns=new_columns)
```

Comment: thanks but I just noticed the names I want to take are the row names from valence_data instead of columns. How can I make that happen? They should correspond directly to all columns

Comment: if by `row names` you mean the content of a data frame column, let's call it `names`, you can just replace `new_names` by that column (e.g.: `df["names"].tolist()`. Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

Just do this

```
import pandas as pd
word_data = pd.DataFrame(word_data,columns=list(valence_data))
```

But the number of columns in both dataframes should be equal