# Change column names using *plyr where the mapping is given by two columns of another data frame

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyr, plyr

I have a simple data frame `a`

```
  x  y
1 1 11
2 2 22
3 3 33
```

and another one `b`

```
  old  new
1   x haha
2   y hoho
```

which gives the mapping of the old column names to new column names. I want the following data frame `c`.

```
  haha hoho
1    1   11
2    2   22
3    3   33
```

Note that the actual `a` has lots of columns and the mapping of the two columns in `b` are not straight forward. Also, the rows of `b` **may not** be in the same order as the columns of `a`.

Is it possible to do using `plyr/dplyr`? Something like this in python: [Changing dataframe columns names by columns from another dataframe python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54647472/changing-dataframe-columns-names-by-columns-from-another-dataframe-python)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a great opportunity to use `!!`:

```r
library(tidyverse)

data <- tribble(
  ~x, ~y,
  1,  11,
  2,  22,
  3,  33
)

name_tbl <- tribble(
  ~old, ~new,
  "x",  "haha",
  "y",  "hoho"
)

(name_pairs <- with(name_tbl, set_names(old, new)))
#> haha hoho 
#>  "x"  "y"

rename(data, !!name_pairs)
#> # A tibble: 3 x 2
#>    haha  hoho
#>   <dbl> <dbl>
#> 1     1    11
#> 2     2    22
#> 3     3    33
```

<sup>Created on 2019-10-21 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

`rename()` uses name-value pairs (with the new names as the names), so we just need to 1) take the vector of old names, 2) give it the names of the new names, and 3) call `rename()` with the named vector, unquoted since we're passing the pairs as an object value rather than as syntax.

Comment: Thank you, @DHW. These simple tricks are not mentioned in the documentation of tidyverse functions. I knew that it must be something related to named vectors. But the description of `rename` does not mention that you could pass a named vector.

Comment: The description doesn't, true, but it is to be found in one of the arguments: `The arguments in ... are automatically quoted and evaluated in a context where column names represent column positions. They also support unquoting and splicing. See vignette("programming") for an introduction to these concepts.` Check out the last example, also: `# For convenience it also supports strings and character
# vectors. This is unlike other verbs where strings would be
# ambiguous.
vars <- c(var1 = "cyl", var2 ="am")
select(mtcars, !!vars)
rename(mtcars, !!vars)`